# UITextView crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uitextview

On iOS6 this cod works (myTextView is an instance variable):

```
myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
myTextView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
[self addSubview:myTextView];
```

And on iOS5 it crashes on line:

```
[myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

But the strangest thing it that situation is: if i set `keyboardType` to `UIKeyboardTypeEmail` - no crashes!

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you releasing `myTextView`? Is this using ARC?

Comment: Yes, it is using  ARC

Comment: Where are you calling `[myTextView becomeFirstResponder];`? Is it in same method as in `myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];`?

Comment: Nope. May be, this crash is connected with working with UITextView not in main thread? But in this case, why on ios5 UIKeyboardTypeDefault causes crash, but UIKeyboardTypeEmail works fine?

Comment: In that case your code will crash. You should declare `myTextView` as an @property and use it as `self.myTextView` everywhere. That will fix the crash.

Comment: I of course declared myTextView as instance variable

Comment: Stil it is better to use @property. The scope of `myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];` is inside that method only and since you are trying to access somewhere, that particular memory location might get released at times.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the mention of usage of background thread here. Yes, you should do UI operations in main thread.

Comment: But addSubview: will retain myTextView. Also, if this is ivar, it is by default __strong, and should retain relevant object as well, right?

Comment: Do you set textview delegate? If yes, make sure the textview (or subclass thereof) is not its own delegate. You should also take a look at crash logs generated on device. They can be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Never call UIKit methods on threads other than the main thread. If it works, that's just luck.

And please, next time you ask a question, do provide more detail in your actual questions, so people won't have to go through the comments to find the actual issue.

Comment: I am not sure, that i perform [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
 not on the main thread (it is my hypothesis), but it is possible. And when i set keyboardType to UIKeyboardTypeEmail, in tis case no crashes ever

Comment: Well, then you really need to post more context (which probably means code). Otherwise, all anybody could do is just guess.

Comment: ok, i think, may be this crash connected with some known issue. if it is not, only i can solve my problem =)